HOW to remove recaptcha from otp authentication Android jetpack compose using Firebase authentication
I have developed OTP Authentication page using Android Kotlin Jetpack composer using Firebase authentication, Now in that how can remove the Recaptcha, without that how can i directly authenticate using otp .
I tried google console, their api but not able find proper solutions

This topic has come up multiple times before. I linked a few of the existing issues, but I also recommend searching for them. If you think your issue is different than all of those, edit it (there's a small edit link under your question) to include exact steps of what you did and how your situation differs from (the answers to) those other questions.
